# JavaScript RegExp exec function

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got an input that someone may type in the following pattern:

> property:value

That pattern may evolve into multiple instances of the same pattern with some variance. For example

> property:value property2:"value2" property3>"value3" -property4:"value4"

So in the example above, each pattern could begin with the literal character '-' but it doesn't have to, each pattern could contain the literal characters of :>< and additionally, each pattern may have its value quoted with double quotes, or it may not. What I've discovered is that my previous attempt at creating a new RegExp and then using an exec function on a value is not cutting the match off where I want it to, so using the example above, it would match:

> property:value property2

Here is the RegExp that I used initially, which I did my best to adjust but ending up falling down a few rabbit holes. I attempted to tell it to match up until a particular character class, but with bad results.

```
var findFilters = new RegExp(/-?\w+[:<>]"?[A-Za-z\S\s]+"?/ig)
```

Also, here is what I'm using afterward in my function. I'm taking each match and passing it as a parameter to another function. searchTerm represents the value of the input that the user can type in.

```
var match;
while(match = findFilters.exec(searchTerm)){
    var currentFilter = match[0];
    HSAddFilterParameter(currentFilter);
    updatedTerm = searchTerm.replace(currentFilter,'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just split the string with those characters as separators: - : < > \s  ?
Then grab them from the array two at a time. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="answer"></p>
    <script>
        var foo = 'property:value  property2:"value2"  property3>"value3"  -property4:"value4"';

        arr =  foo.split(/[-:<>\s]+/);
        str = "";
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) { 
            str = str + arr[i] + " : " + arr[i+1] + " <br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = str;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
property : value 
property2 : "value2" 
property3 : "value3" 
property4 : "value4"
```